# Unable to make multiple foreign keys from a single primary-key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I am trying to do but sql is not allowing me to do so. Please suggest me the alternatives if this is not possible.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried that SQL does not allow you to do ?

Comment: Please don't write the title in all caps. Also, please include the query you have tried.

Comment: 1. Show us the code you tried 2. which columns have indexes (perhaps just post the code to create the table and the indexes, 3. In the code you post, what challenges do you experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can sure be achieved. Consider the following table definitions:

```
create table Tbl_Course(
    CrsId int primary key, 
    CrsName varchar(100)
);

create table Tbl_Student(
    StdId int primary key,
    StdCourse1 int,
    StdCourse2 int,
    StdCourse3 int,
    foreign key (StdCourse1) references Tbl_Course(CrsId),
    foreign key (StdCourse2) references Tbl_Course(CrsId),
    foreign key (StdCourse3) references Tbl_Course(CrsId)
);
```

With this set up in place, you can insert your sample data:

```
insert into Tbl_Course values
    (1001, 'MATHS'),
    (1002, 'PHYSICS'),
    (1003, 'CHEMISTRY'),
    (1004, 'ARTS');

insert into Tbl_Student values
    (1, 1001, 1002, 1003),
    (2, 1002, 1003, 1004),
    (3, 1004, null, null);
```

If you try to insert a value in the child table that does not exists in the parent table, then you would get an error:

```
insert into Tbl_Student values(4, 1005, null, null);
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Tbl_Stude__StdCo__38996AB5"

However it should be noted that the design of table `Tbl_Student` is not normalized. What if a student participates more than 3 courses? You would need to add more columns to your table. How do you check if a user participates a given course? You need to check in 3 different columns. For an alternative design that follows standard normalization rules, see below answer from Dai.

Comment: Your design doesn't work if a student wants to take more than 3 courses. It also allows a student to be in the same course 3 times. Is that desirable or correct?

Comment: @Dai: I do agree, and I added a mention about that in my answer. My answer was meant to answer the original question from OP about creating serveral foreing keys referencing the same table/column.

Comment: @GMB I am unable to do this graphically

Answer (score 1):

[Your design is not correctly normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Don't express multiple relations using columns, instead use rows.

Also, Hungarian Notation is frowned-upon. Avoid object identifier prefixes like "`Tbl_`". And there is no need to use abbreviations in column names. Always use full spelling where possible so that other people can understand your system (aka "self-documenting code").

Consider a design like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTIY(1,1),
    -- etc
)

CREATE TABLE Courses (
    CourseId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTIY(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    -- etc
)

CREATE TABLE StudentsInCourses (
    StudentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Composite primary key
    CourseId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( StudentId ) REFERENCES Students ( StudentId ),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( CourseId ) REFERENCES Courses ( CourseId )
)
```

This design allows students to participate in zero or more courses with no upper-limit, and allows the student-in-course relation to be directly queried using a `JOIN` [and other relational operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), whereas your design doesn't work if a student wants to do more than 3 courses - or if you want to run a query involving students taking a course that could be any-of `Course1`, `Course2`, or `Course3` in your design.

Additionally, because both columns participate in a composite primary key in `StudentsInCourses` the design makes it impossible for a student to be in the same course more than once (if this is not desirable then please update your Question posting with more specific requirements)